# Two dimensional matrix as List of lists

Tags: python, list, matrix

I am beginner  in python. I  have a 3*3 matrix .I want to perform certain operations in that matrix, like matrix multiplication addition etc. I have represented my matrix as a list of lists as given below:

```
mat =[[23,45],[45,67],[24,56]]
```

Is there any inbuilt function for list to perform matrix multiplication, or do I need to write a separate function for it? Is there any better way to multiply two matrix?

Answer (score 1):

There is no build-in functions for matrix operation, that's why packages like [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/) exist.

```
import numpy as np
mat = np.array([[23,45],[45,67],[24,56]])
np.dot(mat, mat.T)
# array([[2554, 4050, 3072],
#       [4050, 6514, 4832],
#       [3072, 4832, 3712]])
```